# Checking if a letter == a specified letter in Java

Tags: java, variables, while-loop

I am trying to perform a check to make sure the letter typed by the user is between A and E. I have tried several different ways, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated. The main problem is, it only checks once. After it tells me I need to enter a letter between A and E, and I put g, it allows the program to continue running afterwards.

```
 System.out.println("Please enter a letter indicating your tax category: A is no tax deduction, B is 10% of gross pay, \nC is 20% of gross pay, D is 29% of gross pay, E is 35% of gross pay");
 //use ASCII of letters to compare
int A_ASCII = (int)'A';
int E_ASCII = (int)'E';
int ASCIIletter = 0;
// ask user for letter
letter = in.next().charAt(0);
// convert letter to uppercase and find ASCII value
if(Character.isLetter(letter)){ 
 letter = Character.toUpperCase(letter);
 ASCIIletter = (int) letter;
while (ASCIIletter>=A_ASCII&&ASCIIletter<=E_ASCII) {
if(ASCIIletter>=A_ASCII&&ASCIIletter<=E_ASCII){ 
if (ASCIIletter=='A'||ASCIIletter=='a'){
  letter = letter;
  gross = gross;
}
else if (ASCIIletter=='B'||ASCIIletter=='b'){
 letter = letter;
 deduct = (gross*0.1);
 tax = gross - deduct;  
}
 else if (ASCIIletter=='C'||ASCIIletter=='c'){
 letter = letter;
 deduct = (gross*0.2);
 tax = gross - deduct;
}
 else if (ASCIIletter=='D'||ASCIIletter=='d'){
 letter = letter;
 deduct = (gross*0.29);
 tax = gross - deduct;
} 
else if (ASCIIletter=='E'||ASCIIletter=='e'){
letter = letter;
deduct = (gross*0.35);
tax = gross - deduct;
}
}
 else { 
System.out.println("You must enter a letter between A and E.");
letter = in.next().charAt(0);
}
}
```

Comment: Is `letter` a `char` or a `String`?

Comment: Do you tried to use the equals? For example: letter.equals("A");?!

Comment: @TiagoBarreto I will try that, but which part do you mean?

Comment: So, if the letter is a char, forget the equals. :)

Comment: @TiagoBarreto in which part should I forget the equals?

Comment: How specifically does this not work?  In any case, a statement like `letter = letter` does nothing useful, but I don't know if there was something else you were trying to accomplish by this statement, or it's there fore some other reason.

Comment: `(letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'E') || (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'e')`

Comment: Can't you just change your 'while' to a 'if'. You have an infinite loop otherwise.

Comment: Another issue: I don't know what A, B, ..., E mean, but if they enter `A`, you never set `tax` to anything.  Is that correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26413406/4151328 @ajb this is the full program

Comment: You still haven't told us what the problem is.  My guess: you're getting errors about variables not being initialized.  Is that right, or is it something else?

Comment: @ajb no errors at all just that it only checks if the letter is between A and E once nothing more but when I add the while statement like above, it gets stuck in an infinite loop if the letter is between A and E

Comment: Which `while` statement?  The one near the top, or the one near the bottom?

Comment: @ajb not really sure, I'm a beginner

Comment: No, you said you added a `while` statement and then it got stuck.  Which one did you add?  I hope the answer isn't "you're not sure"... :) :)

Comment: @ajb I added the top one first and then when that didn't work I added the second to check it again

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer.  Note: I typed this edit in before your latest change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know specifically how this doesn't work.  However, there's definitely a problem in the code that handles invalid entries.

If you want to compare `letter` to see if it equals one of two or more characters, you can say

```
if (letter == 'A' || letter == 'a')
```

However, if you want to make sure it does *not* equal *any* of those, you must change `||` to `&&` in addition to changing `==` to `!=`:

```
if (letter != 'A' && letter != 'a')
```

The reason is that the language will take your code literally.  In English, we might say "if the letter isn't A or B or C".  But in a program, if you say

```
if (letter != 'A' || letter != 'a')
```

Suppose `letter` is `'A'`.  Now the first operand, `letter != 'A'`, is `false`.  But the second operand, `letter != 'a'`, is `true`, because `'A' != 'a'`.  And with `||`, if either operand is `true`, the whole result is `true`.  In fact, this `if` statement will be `true` regardless of what `letter` is.  That isn't what you want.  So either use `&&`, or write it like this:

```
if (!(letter == 'A' || letter == 'a'))
```

By putting the whole `||` in parentheses and negating it with `!`, you're guaranteed to get the opposite result of

```
if (letter == 'A' || letter == 'a')
```

**MORE:** To answer the question in the comments: The reason you're in an infinite loop is this: You ask the user for a letter.  Then you say, essentially,

```
while (letter [is one of the valid ones]) { 
    if (letter is A) {
        ...
    }
    else if (letter is B) {
        ...
    } ... then all the other letters
    else 
        ... try to get the user to enter another letter ------B
}
[past the end of the while]  ------A
```

The way `while` works is this: It checks if the condition is true.  If it's false, it jumps past the end of the `while`, to point A in the above.  If it's true, it executes all the code in the loop, and then goes back up to the top, and checks the condition again.

So if the user enters an invalid letter, the program skips over the whole loop, to point A.  It will never get to the code where you tell the user to try again.  If the letter is valid, the program executes all your logic to compute the tax and whatever--**and then it goes back up to the top**, and since `letter` hasn't changed, the condition is still true, and it goes through the loop again, and again, ...

It looks like you wanted the loop just to get the user to enter another letter if the first letter was invalid.  Since that's the case, you want a `while` loop that *stops* when the letter is valid, and *keeps going* when the letter is invalid.  That means you want a `while` condition that tests whether the letter is invalid, so that you exit the loop when it's valid--and then, after you exit the loop, you want to execute all your tax logic, which means that the computation has to happen *after* the end of the `while` loop.  Something like:

```
System.out.println("Please enter a letter indicating your tax category: A is no tax deduction, B is 10% of gross pay, \nC is 20% of gross pay, D is 29% of gross pay, E is 35% of gross pay");
letter = in.next().charAt(0);
while (letter!='A'&&letter!='a'&&letter!='B'...) { // WHILE THE LETTER IS INVALID 
    System.out.println("You must enter a letter between A and E.");
    letter = in.next().charAt(0);
}
NOW DO ALL THE COMPUTATION
```

I've tried to answer this in a way that shows you why your code wasn't working, and what small changes you could make to fix it.  But please read the other suggestions for other ways you can improve your code.

Answer (score 1):

You better use the [`switch-case`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement:

```
char letter = in.next().charAt(0);
boolean isValid = true;
switch (letter) {
case 'A': case 'a':
    break;
case 'B': case 'b':
    deduct = gross*0.1;
    break;
case 'C': case 'c':
    deduct = gross*0.2;
    break;
case 'D': case 'd':
    deduct = gross*0.29;
    break;
case 'E': case 'e':
    deduct = gross*0.35;
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("You must enter a letter between A and E.");
    isValid = false;
    break;
}
if (isValid) {
    tax = gross - deduct;
}
```

About your test `letter != 'A' || letter != 'a'` ... trying to negate `letter == 'A' || letter == 'a'` ..., remember the [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)".

Or

> `!(A || B)` is the same as `(!A) && (!B)`

So the negation of `letter == 'A' || letter == 'a'` ... is `letter != 'A' && letter != 'a'` ...

Answer (score 1):

There's a lit of unnecessary code in there. I would first clean things up by writing a method that handles user input and validation:

```
private static char readTax(Scanner in) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a letter indicating your tax category: A is no tax deduction, B is 10% of gross pay, \nC is 20% of gross pay, D is 29% of gross pay, E is 35% of gross pay");
        char letter = in.next().charAt(0);
        letter = Character.toUpperCase(letter);
        if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'E')
            return letter;
    }
    return ' '; // needed to compile
}
```

This method won't return unless the user enters a valid letter, and it returns it in upper case.

Once you've done that and used it, you can then clean up your main code by removing the main loop (because you know you have valid input), something like this:

```
char letter = readTax(in);
double tax = 0; // tax for 'A'
switch (letter) {
    case 'B': tax = 0.1; break;
    case 'C': tax = 0.2; break;
    case 'D': tax = 0.29; break;
    case 'E': tax = 0.35;
}
deduct = gross * tax;
gross -= deduct;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to solve your problem.
First you can transform the letters to upper or lower case, than you don't have a duplication in your checking.
Second use the ASCII-representation to compare between 'A' and 'E':

```java
System.out.println("Please enter a letter indicating your tax category: A is no tax deduction, B is 10% of gross pay, \nC is 20% of gross pay, D is 29% of gross pay, E is 35% of gross pay");


int A_ASCII = (int)'A';
int E_ASCII = (int)'E';

int letterInASCII = -1;


letter = in.next().charAt(0);

if(Character.isLetter(letter)){ 
  letter = Character.toUpperCase(letter);
  letterInASCII = (int) letter;

  if(letterInASCII >= A_ASCII && letterInASCII <= E_ASCII){ // your letter is between A and E
    // do your stuff here                               
  }else{ // your letter is not between A and E
    // do your stuff here                                                                                 
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried this, but again the problem of only checking once occurs

Comment: Yes sure. I only give you some improvements and not the whole solution. For sure you have to add a while loop etc.